# Airflow S3KeySensor task fail

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I’m trying to do is to use ‘S3KeySensor’ to check one data’s availability (the data is already there) and then use ‘DatabricksSubmitRunOperator’ to run one Databricks job. The S3KeySensor task fails within a few seconds, and the downstream tasks fails after that.

In the heartbeat log, there is no details about why inputsensor fails, there is even one line saying ‘Executor reports Emily_example_databricks_operator_3.inputsensor execution_date=2018-03-20 11:15:00 as success’. And after that, it keeps saying ‘No task to send to the executor’ and repeats itself over and over again. Here is the log: [Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ji7Tq.png)

This is the corresponding Python code:

```
inputsensor = S3KeySensor(
  task_id='inputsensor',
  bucket_key='/shard-conviva-databricks-vpc/0/_Projects/Huawei/checks/validity/dt%3D2018_03_05_08_to_2018_03_12_08/impactSummary.csv',
  wildcard_match=True,
  bucket_name='convivaoregon',
  s3_conn_id='my_conn_S3',
  soft_fail=False,
  poke_interval=50,
  timeout=50,
  dag=dag
)

notebook_task = DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(
   task_id='notebook_task',
   dag=dag,
   json=notebook_task_params,
   databricks_conn_id='databricks_conviva'
)

notebook_task.set_upstream(inputsensor)
```

This is the data in Databricks I'm trying to check availability for:

[image]

I've already reached out to the Databricks support but they're saying this is out of their scope.

Thank you!

Comment: You should post your code directly rather than a screen shot.  Images make it hard for people to help you.

Comment: anyone could help me with this? thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information about the error message or the stack trace.

Comment: Just put more info about the error and log, any suggestions/comments are welcome! thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put the log output directly rather that a screenshot. Also, shouldn't the `timeout` be much much higher than the poke interval?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `/` in the bucket key.

try:

```
bucket_key='shard-conviva-databricks-vpc/0/_Projects/Huawei/checks/validity/dt%3D2018_03_05_08_to_2018_03_12_08/impactSummary.csv'
```

To check it, you can see the message in the log of the particular dag.